# LaTeX does not get converted to Math Text unless the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, latex

I am using mimetex.cgi to convert LaTeX text into Maths Text. For which I have put the following in the head tag

```
<head>
    <script src="../../asciimath/js/ASCIIMathMLwFallback.js" type="text/javascript">    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var AScgiloc = '../../includes/svgimg.php';
        var AMTcgiloc = "http://www.imathas.com/cgi-bin/mimetex.cgi";
    </script>
</head>
```

In the body tag I have the following div which is refreshed by ajax. This contains math text.

```
<div id="mathtext"> .... </div>
```

Problem that I am facing:
On the first page load the LaTeX code in `mathtext` div is getting converted to Math Text image. However, when the div is loaded with new LaTeX code using ajax, it doesn't get converted to Math Text.
If I click on refresh, the LaTeX gets converted to MathText again.

I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong here.

Edit 1: Including the onload function that is a part of  ASCIIMathMLwFallback.js

```
if(typeof window.addEventListener != 'undefined')
 {
  //.. gecko, safari, konqueror and standard
  window.addEventListener('load', generic, false);
 }
else if(typeof document.addEventListener != 'undefined')
 {
  //.. opera 7
  document.addEventListener('load', generic, false);
 }
 else if(typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined')
 {
  //.. win/ie
  window.attachEvent('onload', generic);
  }
  //** remove this condition to degrade older browsers
 else
  {
   //.. mac/ie5 and anything else that gets this far
   //if there's an existing onload function
   if(typeof window.onload == 'function')
   {
     //store it
    var existing = onload;
    //add new onload handler
   window.onload = function()
    {
      //call existing onload function
      existing();
      //call generic onload function
      generic();
    };
   }
 else
   {
   //setup onload function
    window.onload = generic;
    }
 }

if (checkForMathML) {
      checkForMathML = false;
      var nd = AMisMathMLavailable();
      AMnoMathML = (nd != null);
  }
```

It calls a function generic() using the above... I guess it would do if I call this function at the end of my ajax query ?

Comment: You will probably have to force the conversion manually after loading the LaTeX code via Ajax. You'll have to check your 3rd party library's documentation to know how to do that.

Comment: The javascript is available on [link](https://code.google.com/p/imathas/source/browse/trunk/javascript/ASCIIMathMLwFallback.js?r=632)
I went through the code., It uses
 window.addEventListener('load', generic, false)  to initiate

Answer (score 0):

Solved it !
ASCIIMathMLwFallback.js has a function called as generic() which is being called on page load here.This function translates Latex into math functions.

In order to convert latex to math function using a ajax query , simply call the generic function by adding the below to the ajax code.

```
generic.call();
```

This will ensure that all Latex is converted to math !!